# How to setup Associated Domains / Universal Links

Tags: ios, reactjs, firebase, ios-universal-links, applinks

I am trying to redirect the user to the installed app when visiting *[www.example.com/success](http://www.example.com/success)* as well as show a banner when visiting the homepage *[www.example.com](http://www.example.com)*.

With my current implantation the url DOES NOT redirect and open the app and neither does the website display a banner.

I am following the documentation found here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/supporting_associated_domains

My website is a simple `create-react-app` with a homepage hosted with Firebase.

I have done the following:

1. Add Associated Domains to Signing and Capabilities - *applinks:website.com/success*
2. Add `apple-app-site-association` file to /public/
3. Amend firebase.json file
4. Link to files in index.html

What I am using to validate:

https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator/

https://search.developer.apple.com/appsearch-validation-tool

Testing by adding [www.example.com/success](http://www.example.com/success) link to notes and opening, It always opens in safari. I Have also tried reinstalling the app and restarting the phone.

**Apple API Validation**

I have uploaded a new app version with associated domains to the store

[image]

**Branch.io**

```
{
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": []
    }
}
```

When visiting [www.example.com/apple-app-site-association](http://www.example.com/apple-app-site-association)

> { "activitycontinuation": { "apps": [ "team.com.example.com" ] },
> "applinks": { "apps": [], "details": [ { "appID":
> "team.com.example.com", "paths": [ "/", "/*", "/success", "/success/*",] }, "webcredentials": { "apps": [
> "team.com.example.com" ] } }

**apple-app-site-association**

```
{
  "activitycontinuation": {
      "apps": [
        "team.com.example.com"
      ]
  },
  "applinks": {
      "apps": [],
      "details": [
            {
                "appID": "team.com.example.com",
                "paths": [
                  "/",
                  "/*", 
                  "/success",
                  "/success/*", 
                ]
            },
      ]
  },
  "webcredentials": {
      "apps": [
        "team.com.example.com"
      ]
  }
}
```

**Index.html**

```
<link rel="apple-app-site-association file" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/apple-app-site-association">
<link rel="apple-app-site-association file" href="/apple-app-site-association">
<meta name="App" content="app-id=XXX, app-argument=https://apps.apple.com/US/app/APP/idXXX, affiliate- data=optionalAffiliateData">
```

**Firebase.json**

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "headers": [
      {
        "source": "/apple-app-site-association",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "Content-Type",
            "value": "application/json"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "appAssociation": "NONE"
  }
}
```

**Device Console**

When installing the app I monitor the device console in Xcode looking through `swdc` process logs for anything related to associated domains or requests. Here's some I found;

> Error getting enterprise-managed associated domains data. If this
> device is not enterprise-managed, this is normal: Error
> Domain=SWCErrorDomain Code=1701 "Failed to get associated domain data
> from ManagedConfiguration framework."
> UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Failed to get associated domain data from
> ManagedConfiguration framework., Line=298, Function=}

> Entry { s = applinks, a = , d = au….ub….com, ua = unspecified,
> sa = approved } needs its JSON updated because the app PI changed

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1916/_index.html

Comment: "I am trying to redirect the user to the installed app when visiting www.example.com/app"... Do you literally mean example.com or you just avoiding posting your real domain? Cause you can't associate a domain that you do not own (not have write access to it)...

Comment: @A.Roe, Do I understand correctly? you wanna add a link to your website, then if user will be on a Device with existing Native Application and click on it, the Native Application raise and if not follow the website route. correct?

Comment: @Alladinian Yes I know, I am just hiding my domain

Comment: @AmerllicA no, when a user opens a url for example, www.example.com/app the app is opened instead. If they visit www.example.com an app banner should be displayed.

Comment: @A.Roe, Another question, Does this `www.example.com` belong to you? by you description I guess, you wanna raise `App` by any website with sub-route of `/App`. correct? or it is just about your own website?

Comment: @AmerllicA Yes, I own the domain and have the website hosted. Not literally `www.exaple.com`

Comment: Make sure you put the apple-app-site-association file in the location www.example.com/.well-known/apple-app-site-association . Points to note: file must be with Public read permission and without an extension. Each time you test the associated domain make sure to reinstall the app.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First  at your device logs and your JSON format it seems your should be following the example shown here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/supporting_associated_domains

In your logs it may shows logs from other apps who also have the outdated API format. However this should not be so much of an issue.

```
{
  "applinks": {
      "details": [
           {
             "appIDs": [ "ABCDE12345.com.example.app", "ABCDE12345.com.example.app2" ],
             "components": [
               {
                  "#": "no_universal_links",
                  "exclude": true,
                  "comment": "Matches any URL whose fragment equals no_universal_links and instructs the system not to open it as a universal link"
               },
               {
                  "/": "/buy/*",
                  "comment": "Matches any URL whose path starts with /buy/"
               },
               {
                  "/": "/help/website/*",
                  "exclude": true,
                  "comment": "Matches any URL whose path starts with /help/website/ and instructs the system not to open it as a universal link"
               },
               {
                  "/": "/help/*",
                  "?": { "articleNumber": "????" },
                  "comment": "Matches any URL whose path starts with /help/ and which has a query item with name 'articleNumber' and a value of exactly 4 characters"
               }
             ]
           }
       ]
   },
   "webcredentials": {
      "apps": [ "ABCDE12345.com.example.app" ]
   },
    "appclips": {
        "apps": ["ABCED12345.com.example.MyApp.Clip"]
    }
}
```

Secondly following the steps in Apple's troubleshooting and your problem I am guessing your problem might be Step 7

- Your app returned false from one of the following
  UIApplicationDelegate protocol methods:
  application(*:continueUserActivity:restorationHandler:),
  application(*:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:),
  application(_:didFInishLaunchingWithOptions:).

  This can happen if you
  parsed the URL that is passed into these methods, and you implemented
  logic to determine that your app can not use this URL.

You have not posted how you handle the URL. You need to implement the `UIUserActivityRestoring` method as suggested in the other answer for it to work. Here is a SwiftUI version

```
ContentView()   
    .onContinueUserActivity(NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb) { userActivity in
        
        print("Continue activity \(userActivity)")
        guard let url = userActivity.webpageURL else {
            return
        }
        
        print("User wants to open URL: \(url)")
        // TODO same handling as done in onOpenURL()

    }
```

Also add

```
.onOpenURL { url in
    print("URL OPENED")
    print(url) // parse the url to get someAction to determine what the app needs do
    if url.relativeString == "example://success" {

    }
}
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1916/_index.html

Comment: NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb is what?

Comment: i'll give you a thumb up if you answer this one

Answer (score 6):

There needs to be an appID in the `apple-app-site-association`:

```
{
  "applinks": {
    "apps": [],
    "details": [
    {
      "appID": "XXXXXXXXXX.com.example.UniveralLinks",
      "paths": ["*"]
    }
    ]
  }
}
```

The applinks tag determines which apps are associated with the web site. Leave the apps value as an empty array. Inside the details tag is an array of dictionaries for linking appIDs and URL paths. For simplicity, you use the * wildcard character to associate all of this web site’s links with the UniversalLinks app. You can limit the paths value to specific folders or file names.
The appID consists of your team ID combined with the app’s bundle ID, but you’ll need to use the identifier for your own account.
Apple assigned you a team ID when you created your Apple developer account. You can find it in the Apple developer center. Log into the web site, click on Membership, then look for Team ID in the Membership Information section.

Now you have the apple-app-site-association it must be uploaded to the web server.
You **must have “write access”** to the web site to do this. Be sure you set up the `apple-app-site-association` file correctly (either at the root or in `.well-known/` on your web server, and no redirects).

You'll also have to add the appropriate entitlements for universal linking to the iOS app.
If you're using Xcode:

1. Select the project.
2. Select the target.
3. Select the Capabilities tab.
4. Scroll to and turn ON Associated Domains.

Then you can add e.g. `applinks:www.mywebsite.in` under `Capabilities -> Associated Domains.

Or in your entitlements file, you can add something like the following:

```
<key>com.apple.developer.associated-domains</key>
<array>   
    ...
    <string>applinks:www.mywebsite.in</string>
    ...
</array>
```

Handling Universal Links:
Now that the app and the web site are officially aware of each other, all the app needs is code to handle the link when it’s called.

```
func application(
  _ application: UIApplication,
  continue userActivity: NSUserActivity,
  restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?
) -> Void) -> Bool {
  
  // 1
  guard userActivity.activityType == NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb,
    let url = userActivity.webpageURL,
    let components = URLComponents(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: true) else {
      return false
  }
  
  // 2 // dig out component for deepLinking reference. 
  if let component = ItemHandler.sharedInstance.items
    .filter({ $0.path == components.path}).first {
    //handle navigation to page indicated by component
    return true
  }
  
  // 3
  if let webpageUrl = URL(string: "http://universal-links-final.example.com") {
    application.open(webpageUrl)
    return false
  }
  
  return false
}
```

iOS calls this method whenever the user taps a universal link related to the app. Here’s what each step does:
First, you verify that the passed-in userActivity has expected characteristics. Ultimately, you want to get the path component for the activity. Otherwise, you return false to indicate that the app can’t handle the activity.
Using the path, you look for a known view controller that matches it. If you find one, you present the view controller for it and return true.
If you can’t find a view controller that matches the path, you instruct the application to open the URL, which will use the default system app instead — most likely Safari. You also return false here to indicate that the app can’t handle this user activity.

Comment: thank you, I have edited my `apple-app-site-association` file and already followed the steps you mentioned. Unfortunately still no luck

Comment: Is the func  ‘continue userActivity’  getting hit?

Comment: well no, because the app doesn't open so it won't right

Comment: Also get the error - Cannot find 'ItemHandler' in scope

Comment: This looks like a decent troubleshooting guide its a little old (take that into account) but seems through. https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1916/_index.html

Comment: I don't know where you guys are getting this JSON. At least, at Apple's docs its totally different for applinks: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/supporting-associated-domains

Comment: where did "NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb" come from please?

Comment: Do you know what the best way is to handle universal links for different targets within the same project? My links are not different but I'm not redirected to the most recently installed app like in Android.